# How to make a popup in ASP.Net and pass information to it using a query string?

Tags: asp.net, response.redirect, request.querystring, onclientclick

I have all the code I need to `response.redirect` a page and pass the information I need to the other page. But I don't want it to redirect the page but rather create a popup in the page. 
I have code for the popup also but I can't manage to pass information to it.

This is the code for the popup and it's not passing any information:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lb_viewstudenttimetable" runat="server" OnClick="lb_viewstudenttimetable_Click" 
     OnClientClick="window.open('Timetable_User.aspx','Timetable','width=640,height=360,scrollbars=yes');">
```

This is the code for the `OnClick` button where it passing information to the other page

```
protected void lb_viewstudenttimetable_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow row = gv_classlist.SelectedRow;
    Response.Redirect("Timetable_User.aspx?UserID=" + row.Cells[1].Text + "");
    //my attempt of trying to pass the following to the popup        
    //Response.Write("window.open('Timetable_User.aspx?UserID="+row.Cells[1].Text+"','Timetable','width=640,height=360,scrollbars=yes');");
}
```

So I wanna use `OnClientClick` to do what that `OnClick` does.

Comment: use ajax model popup with iframes

Comment: Making popups in actual seperate browser windows is a bad idea. It's difficult to control them and difficult to pass information to/from them. And it's often inconvenient for users. Instead, use a proper client side solution such as the [ModalPopupExtender](http://www.asp.net/AjaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/ModalPopup/ModalPopup.aspx) from the Ajax Control Toolkit (by Microsoft) or jQuery UI's [Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/) or some other library.

Comment: its just the fact that i was passing information to another page that would help with getting the information i wanted without writing too much code. I would use a modalpopup, i have for most of my site but in this instance the above method save alot of time which i didnt have. If i had the time i would implemented it in another way but you can beat 3 lines of code lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    GridViewRow row = gv_classlist.SelectedRow;
    lbl_timetableuserid.Text = row.Cells[1].Text;


    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(string), "New_Window", "window.open('Timetable_User.aspx?UserID=" + row.Cells[1].Text + "', null, 'height=360,width=640,status=yes,toolbar=yes,menubar=yes,location=no' );", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the query string:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lb_viewstudenttimetable" runat="server" 
    OnClick="lb_viewstudenttimetable_Click" 
    OnClientClick="window.open('Timetable_User.aspx?UserID=x', 'Timetable', 'width=640,height=360,scrollbars=yes');">
```

The question is then how to get "x" into the query string when "x" comes from the server. What you need to do is, in the Databinding event of the GridView, build the JavaScript string to be used OnClientClick, then set it. That way, the LinkButton in each grid row will already be prepared for when it is clicked.

Comment: I think i understand what your saying but have no clue how to do it!

Comment: In this case, you should answer your own question, and accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want a pop-up or a new browser tab? If you want a pop up, I generally use iframe like this.

```
<a rel="#popupinit" href="#" uniqenum='<%= serversideUniquenum %>'>Open popup</a>

<div style="background-color: white; top: 30px; text-align:center ; width:100%" id="ShowOrderGrid" >
   <iframe id="iframeid" src='' style="width: 500px; text-align:center ; height: 650px;"></iframe>
</div>

<script>
    $(function () {
        $("a[rel='#popupinit]").click(function () {
            var uniquenum = $(this).attr("uniquenum");
            $('#iframeid').attr('src', '/somepath/somepath/somepage.aspx?uniquenum=' + uniquenum);
        });
</script>
```