# Open .aspx page as Bootstrap modal popup from global.ascx

Tags: asp.net

I have created an Error.aspx page. I have defined Modal popup inside the Master page. I want to open this Error.aspx page as modal popup from global.ascx.
Is is possible?

Comment: you have to add more information please add your code where  u can get error

Answer (score -1):

Once I have same requirement with session lost error message in pop up, so what I did,

1. Checked whether session is alive or not.

> There are many options to achieve this functionality, but I tried to do this for global level because my session is for login (see below url for example).

2. Then, If session is not available,you can check like this.

   ```
   Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Window","window.alert('Show your message here.','');", true);
   ```
3. You can open pop up with HTML/aspx too using some way around.

I might have some syntax errors, but you get the idea...

Some useful urls.

https://forums.asp.net/t/1082125.aspx?How+to+check+whether+a+session+exists+or+not+

https://forums.asp.net/t/1491997.aspx?Popup+window+and+Response+Redirect+

https://forums.asp.net/t/1082125.aspx?How+to+check+whether+a+session+exists+or+not+

https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/856696/Displaying-a-aspx-page-in-a-pop-up-window-on-buttn

[How to make a popup in ASP.Net and pass information to it using a query string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23571093/how-to-make-a-popup-in-asp-net-and-pass-information-to-it-using-a-query-string)

Comment: Actually i am handling application level error in global.aspx. So whenever error occurred in application it is going to application_error event in global.aspx. 
Now i want to show error details to user in modal popup. for that I have created an Error.aspx page which I want to open as bootstrap modal popup to user. But I am unable to open it from global.aspx.

Comment: do this, Add key of your page in web.config, send user to aspx page using this key from Application_Error method, and once your error page is opening successfully, load the content in pop up using document.ready event of javascript, easy..

Comment: send user to aspx page using this key from Application_Error method--which aspx page you are talking about.
I dont want user to redirect to any other page. Just want show a modal popup and if he close modal he should be on the page where error occurred.